# How to get value of Variable[position] in BaseAdapter class - Android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have a BaseAdapter class that uses variables like this

```
listComments[position];
listUsernames[position];
```

How do I find the actual value of these variables? I have tried making an "if statement" like this, but doesn't work.

```
   if (listComments[position] != "null"){  //do something  }
```

I am trying to see if the variable is equal to null then do something but it doesn't work. I believe its because listComments[position]; is not actually comparing the variable value at that position. How can I compare the value of the actual variable at that position to "null"?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing

```
if (listComments[position] != "null"){  //do something  }
```

write it as below:

```
if (!listComments[position].equalsIgnoreCase("")){  //do something  }
```

EDIT: I had forgotten to put "!" at the start of the condition. I just edited.

Answer (score 1):

Never use == for string comparisson.  Use the equals function.  In Java, == checks the references, not the string the references point to.  Its like comparing 2 pointers in C instead of the data they point to.

Answer (score 0):

Gabe Sechan is right, never use '==' for string.
Android provide an util class called TextUtils.
And, TextUtils.isEmpty etc, check if string is null for you.